# How to get the right Google Maps API Key

Tags: android, google-maps

Hy!

I just put my first app in the market. Before the map works on the emulator and my droid very fine. But now after signing and publishing the mapview don't work anymore.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need different Maps API keys for signing debug builds vs release builds.](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)